# "Sensación de que sucede algo", ¿es dequeísmo?

Tags: gramática

Ayer escribí la siguiente frase humorística:

> No hay devaluación. Es solo una *sensación* de que la moneda nacional es papel higiénico.

*(es una referencia a expresiones como "es sólo una sensación de inseguridad")*

Alguien señaló que esa construcción era un dequeísmo, y que debería eliminar el "de". Pero mi impresión es que eso cambiaría el sentido de la frase, y que la misma es correcta tal como está.

¿Es correcta esta apreciación?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tu frase es correcta, y la «corrección» que te sugieren es un error que tienen nombre: [queísmo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=0WI0lLaCjD655ud6n5). Concretamente, mira el punto 1.c:

> **QUEÍSMO**. Es la supresión indebida de una preposición (generalmente *de*)
>   delante de la conjunción *que*, cuando la preposición viene exigida por
>   alguna palabra del enunciado.
>
> **1.** No debe suprimirse la preposición en los casos siguientes:
>
> [...]
>
> **c)** Con sustantivos que llevan complementos preposicionales: *Iré con la*
>   condición ***de que*** vayáis a recogerme (no *Iré con la* condición ***que***
>   *vayáis a recogerme*); *Tengo* ganas ***de que*** llueva (no *Tengo* ganas ***que***
>   *llueva*); *Ardo en* deseos ***de que*** vengas a verme (no *Ardo en* deseos ***que***
>   *vengas a verme*).

Answer (score 7):

Tu frase es correcta, pero es fácil confundirse.

> Tengo la **sensación de que** estás mintiendo. (Correcto)
>
> **Siento que** estás mintiendo. (Correcto)

Parecen construcciones equivalentes, pero no lo son. En la segunda el verbo es transitivo, recae sobre lo que sigue (objeto directo, que es prácticamente exigido): "Siento... siento algo. ¿Qué? Siento esto: ..." (nótese que la pregunta que exige la frase incompleta recae sobre el objeto que falta). En la primera,  el verbo no es transitivo, lo que sigue es un complemento: "Tengo una sensación. (¿Cuál?) Tengo la siguiente sensación: estás mintiendo".

Como regla general: cuando puedo reemplazar toda la construcción por la palabra "**esto**" o "**algo**" (***something***),  como sucede en la segunda frase del ejemplo,  entonces debemos usar "**que**"; caso contrario, hay que usar "**de que**".